# Android grid layout items starting from the center and fill the view if many

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

How to create a layout containing items (displayed in a recyclerview) when their count is few (4 only for example), they would be positioned at the view center, and when their number increases, the grid fills the parent and the items size adapt to the new size (without scroll bars). This is an example from an app I've seen:

[image]

[image]